# What process get killed when I do `ctrl + c`?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, process

My vague and intuitive understanding is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kills the process that is currently running on the selected window.

I am getting confused though typically about the difference of what process get killed when an executable is called and when an interpreter is used.

**Interpreter**

When I use an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)). For example if I open `R` on the terminal, I can see one process which `CMD` (on call of `ps`) is `R`. When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> however, the `R` process does not get killed but the process running in `R` gets killed.

**Executable**

When I call an exectuable, I can see one process which `CMD` (on call of `ps`) is `<nameOfExecutable>`. When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, this process is killed.

**Question**

There seems to have some kind of hierarchy of processes (and there might be a correct semantic to refer to it). What does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> exactly do in the light of this apparent hierarchy of processes?

---

For your information, I use Terminal 2.6.1 on Mac OS X 10.11.3

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6110213/1025421 // Also note that `SIGINT` is not `SIGKILL`, so the process isn't "killed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but `ctrl + c` should send `SIGINT` signal to running process. Usually programs don't have custom handler for this signal and default action is taken (program is killed). I am guessing that interpreter intercepts this signal and simply stop executing running script.